# How to make the checkbox checked default?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, checkbox

I am making a react app where I need to populate dynamic checkboxes from the data.

```
  const sectors = [
    {
      SectorID: 5,
      Name: "Wood Truss/Panel/Building Components"
    },
    {
      SectorID: 33,
      Name: "LBM Retail/Pro Contractor"
    },
    {
      SectorID: 24,
      Name: "Light Gauge Steel Truss/Panel"
    }
  ];
```

Then I do have a list of selected checkboxes here,

```
  const selectedSectors = [
    {
      SectorID: 5
    },
    {
      SectorID: 24
    }
  ];
```

So here using `SectorID`, we can find a match.

**Expected result:** Need to make the selected sector to be checked on load.

**Solution I tried**:

```
  const [checkedItems, setCheckedItems] = useState({});

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const newData = sectors.map((sector) => {
      return selectedSectors.map((selected) => {
        if (selected.SectorId === sector.SectorId) {
          setCheckedItems((prev) => {
            const checkedItems = {
              ...prev.checkedItems,
              [sector.Name]: true
            };
            return { ...prev, checkedItems };
          });
        }
      });
    });
  }, []);
```

The above one doesn't make the selected sectors checked and I think I am doing something wrong here.

**Populating checkboxes like**:

```
      {sectors &&
        sectors.map((sector, index) => (
          <React.Fragment key={index}>
            <label className="block mr-4">
              <input
                className="mx-2 leading-tight"
                name={sector.Name}
                checked={checkedItems[sector.Name]}
                onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(e, sector)}
                type="checkbox"
              />
              <span className="text-sm">{sector.Name}</span>
            </label>
          </React.Fragment>
        ))}
```

Codesandbox:

[image: Edit React Functional Component (forked)]

**Requirement:** Please help me to make the checkboxes get checked by default on comparing with `selectedSectors`..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need to do anything with the checked state then you should use the `defaultChecked` attribute and simply search the `selectedSectors` array for a match.

```
defaultChecked={selectedSectors.some(
  (selectedSector) =>
    selectedSector.SectorID === sector.SectorID
)}
```

If you want to keep your `checkedItems` state then you can initialize your state in the effect. Iterate over the `sectors` array and reduce into an object of sector ids to selected values

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  const defaultCheckedSectors = sectors.reduce(
    (defaultChecked, sector) => ({
      ...defaultChecked,
      [sector.SectorID]: selectedSectors.some(
        (selectedSector) => selectedSector.SectorID === sector.SectorID
      )
    }),
    {}
  );
  setCheckedItems(defaultCheckedSectors);
}, []);
```

Update the `checked` attribute to use the `SectorId`.

```
<input
  className="mx-2 leading-tight"
  name={sector.Name}
  checked={checkedItems[sector.SectorID]} // <-- use SectorID
  onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(e, sector)}
  type="checkbox"
/>
```

You will need to also update `handleInputChange` to consume the sector. *Alternatively you could also just simply pass the `SectorID` value.*

```
const handleInputChange = (event, sector) => { // <-- consume sector
  const { checked } = event.target;
  setCheckedItems(prev => ({
    ...prev,
    [sector.SectorID]: checked // <-- use sector for ID
  }))
};
```

[image: Edit how-to-make-the-checkbox-checked-default]

Comment: I need to check the checked values and pass it down to ```handleInputChange``` to make another set of actions.. I will display another set of data based on the selected sectors..

Comment: Can you provide codesandbox example of your solution please?

Comment: @Undefined Sure... I was in the middle of adding the version if you needed to keep the checked state and added the link to sandbox.

Comment: Could you please help me here? https://stackoverflow.com/q/64604518/13270726

Answer (score 1):

You have no need to create another array with checked items. Just change your input like-

```
<input className="mx-2 leading-tight"
    name={sector.Name}
    checked={!!selectedSectors.find(item => item.SectorID === sector.SectorID)}
    onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(e, sector)}
    type="checkbox" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This whole approach isn't quite the React way to do it. There should be a single source of truth in state that tracks the sectors' values AND if they're checked. And the initial state for `useState` should be used to determine the initially checked status.

See [this code sandbox I forked from yours](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-functional-component-forked-5qk9d?file=/src/index.js) to see it rewritten in a more React-y way

Comment: Why you have hard coded the data inside the ```useState```? I can't hard code anything like that..

Comment: ...because the data was hardcoded in your code? You can easily pass in a dynamic value, though that's a separate thing

Comment: Not necessarily every aspect in React should be "controlled", so you cannot deem a piece of code as "not the react way" without knowing the whole story

Comment: I have hardcoded only the actual data which comes from api in real application..

Comment: @vsync I never said "everything in React should *always* be controlled". I was basing it purely off the question's use case and code provided, in which they wanted to track the checked status of a checkbox and render the UI accordingly. Which is when you use controlled components. Though I probably could've been a bit more specific