# Unable to check/uncheck the checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, checkbox

I am making a react application where checkboxes for jobtitles are populated from the dynamic data from api and it will be exactly like given snippet.

```js
const departments = 
[
   {
      "sectorId":29,
      "sectorName":"Building Materials Mfg. & Distribution",
      "departments":[
         {
            "deptName":"Manufacturing",
            "jobTitles":[
               {
                  "453":false,
                  "JobTitleID":453,
                  "DepartmentID":101,
                  "JobName":"Consultant",
                  "Deleted":false,
                  "SortOrder":5
               },
               {
                  "323":true,
                  "JobTitleID":323,
                  "DepartmentID":101,
                  "JobName":"Quality Control",
                  "Deleted":false,
                  "SortOrder":1
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "deptName":"Warehouse",
            "jobTitles":[
               {
                  "326":false,
                  "JobTitleID":326,
                  "DepartmentID":98,
                  "JobName":"Warehouse Supervisor",
                  "Deleted":false,
                  "SortOrder":1
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "deptName":"Administration",
            "jobTitles":[
               {
                  "384":true,
                  "JobTitleID":384,
                  "DepartmentID":115,
                  "JobName":"Controller",
                  "Deleted":false,
                  "SortOrder":1
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]

  const handleJobTitle = (event, job) => {
    const { checked } = event.target;
    if (checked) {
      document.getElementById(job.JobTitleID).checked = true;
    } else {
      document.getElementById(job.JobTitleID).checked = false;
    }
    console.log(document.getElementById(job.JobTitleID));
  };


const App = () => (
 <div> {departments && departments.map((levelOne, i) => (
            <div
              key={i}
            >
              <p> {levelOne.sectorName} </p>
              {levelOne.departments.map((levelTwo, j) => (
                <div key={j}>
                  <p >
                    {" "}
                    {levelTwo.deptName}{" "}
                  </p>
                  {levelTwo.jobTitles.map((job, l) => (
                    <div
                      key={l}
                    >
                      <input type="checkbox" id={job.JobTitleID} onChange={(e) => {handleJobTitle(e, job)}} name={job.JobName} checked={job[job.JobTitleID]}/>
                      <span>{job.JobName}</span>
                    </div>
                  ))}
                </div>
              ))}
            </div>
          ))} </div>
)

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Here the `jobTitles` data will be like,

```
"jobTitles":[
   {
      "453":false,
      "JobTitleID":453,
      "DepartmentID":101,
      "JobName":"Consultant",
      "Deleted":false,
      "SortOrder":5
   },
   {
      "323":true,
      "JobTitleID":323,
      "DepartmentID":101,
      "JobName":"Quality Control",
      "Deleted":false,
      "SortOrder":1
   }
]
```

And I make the checkbox `checked` based on the value of `"453":false` like,

```
<input type="checkbox" ...... checked={job[job.JobTitleID]}/>
```

And the checkboxes are checked here but when I try to uncheck the checkbox in `onChange` handler like,

```
const handleJobTitle = (event, job) => { 
 document.getElementById(job.JobTitleID).checked = false;
}
```

The checkboxes are not unchecked.. If I console/inspect the input element then the `checked` atribute is **not removed**.

**Additional Info:** It is also not possible to check the checkbox which is in `unchecked` state.. So in common I couldn't make any change to checkbox..

Could anybody please help me to achieve the solution and I am got stuck for too long with this as I am new to react..

Big thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem with direct DOM manipulation/mutation is that this occurs *outside* the react ecosystem; react doesn't know to rerender in order to update the UI. The `job[job.JobTitleID]` value isn't in react state/props and never gets updated.

Comment: @DrewReese, Thanks for your note.. Could you please help me out to achieve the result  using state? I am given the data from api like the above and populated the checkbox accordingly.. So only issue is check/uncheck the checkbox not working and I can understand your explanation.. So could you please provide me a right solution using ```state/props``` in this case please..

Comment: @DrewReese, Bro can you help me in a question where I took the solution from your earlier answer but it doesn't work.. Question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64967082/13270726

Comment: @DrewReese, It is okay if you help in morning your time.. I really believe you would be the right person to answer the question regarding making the scroll to related element ```fieldset``` on click over the selected item.

Comment: @DrewReese, Did you get chance to help me in the above given question? Awaiting for your solution since yesterday.. Please kindly help me Reese..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue(s)

Direct DOM mutation is an anti-pattern in react (it is outside react so react can't know to rerender).

The handler also doesn't access the `checked` property of the `onChange` event.

```
const { checked } = event; // <-- should be event.target
```

## Solution

Use react state to maintain the checked status in component state.

Move the `departments` data into component state.

```
const [departments, setDepartments] = useState(departmentsData);
```

Move the `handleJobTitle` handler into the component. I suggest using a curried function that accepts the sector id, department name, and the job id, you'll need these to "trace" the path to the correct nested object. You don't need to worry about getting the `checked` property from `event.target` as you can simply invert a `checked` value in state via the `JobTitleID` key value.

The idea here is to shallow copy any nested state, into new object references for react, that is being updated.

```
const handleJobTitle = (sectorId, deptName, JobTitleID) => () => {
  setDepartments((data) =>
    data.map((sector) =>
      sector.sectorId === sectorId
        ? {
            ...sector,
            departments: sector.departments.map((dept) =>
              dept.deptName === deptName
                ? {
                    ...dept,
                    jobTitles: dept.jobTitles.map((job) =>
                      job.JobTitleID === JobTitleID
                        ? {
                            ...job,
                            [JobTitleID]: !job[JobTitleID]
                          }
                        : job
                    )
                  }
                : dept
            )
          }
        : sector
    )
  );
};
```

Now simply attach the `handleJobTitle` to the input's `onChange` handler.

```
<input
  type="checkbox"
  id={job.JobTitleID}
  onChange={handleJobTitle( // <-- pass the required values
    levelOne.sectorId,
    levelTwo.deptName,
    job.JobTitleID
  )}
  name={job.JobName}
  checked={job[job.JobTitleID]}
/>
```

[image: Edit unable-to-uncheck-the-checkbox]

Comment: Thanks for your quick help.. And I really appreciate it.. Is it not possible to do things without modifying the original data? Because you have removed the job title id and placed checked there with boolean values.. So isn't possible without modifying that part?

Comment: @Undefined That was for quick demo... you could process your data when the component mounts and compute the checked property, and there isn't a need to remove those odd-ball key-values (into a new object/array reference OFC). For the handler it is better to have a consistent key/property to test for. Let me play with the dynamic keys you had to see what I can get working.

Comment: @Undefined Updated solution to use dynamic keys and not require changes/additions to source data.

Comment: You are awesome and thanks for your change on my request.. Learning from you many things and I once again appreciate your help..

Answer (score 0):

You need to define an Id parameter in the input tag.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="JobTitleCheckBox" ...... checked={job[job.JobTitleID]}/>
```

Then use that id to fetch the node and change its status

```
const handleJobTitle = (event, job) => {
   document.getElementById(job.JobTitleID).checked = false;
}
```